# Full calendar Vuejs (with Laravel) not show button month and week

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar-5

I try make full calendar with buttons dayGridMonth, dayGridWeek. I read official documentation fullcalendar.io and found a solution add right:'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,timeGridDay'. But it doesn't work for me.

Vuejs code:

```
<template>
        <full-calendar ref="fullCalendar"
            :events="calendarEvents"
            :allDaySlot="false"
            :height="1000"
            :header="{
                    left: 'prev, next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                }"

        >
        </full-calendar>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            calendarEvents: [{
                events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/show-events').then(res => {
                        callback(res.data.eventList)
                    })
                },
                color: 'blue',
                textColor: 'white',
            }]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do want to show the events on the calendar?

Comment: Calendar is work but dont show button month, week. (Right buttons)

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/demos for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. I Created a calenderOptions object and passed it to full-calender

```
  <full-calendar ref="fullCalendar" :options="calendarOptions" />
```

In the options, I used headerToobar and alignment top place buttons as shown below.

```
data() {
    return {
        calendarOptions: {
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            allDaySlot:false,
            height:1000,
            events: [
                { title: 'event 1', date: '2021-06-28' },
                { title: 'event 2', date: '2019-04-02' }
            ],
            headerToolbar: { right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay', center: 'title',left: 'prev, next today', },
        },
    }
},
```

The events can also be updated

```
 this.calendarOptions.events = [] //new events
```